# Delete records from table based on fieldflag value using Pentaho PDI

Tags: pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have an ETL which performs a merge rows (diff) then a switch / case statement.  Based on the flagfield value, the switch / case performs different outputs.  I am looking to DELETE the records where flagfield = deleted from a table in the database.  How do I reference the "flagfield = deleted" in a WHERE clause?  Or maybe there is a better approach?  Ultimately, looking to an UPDATE when flagfield = changed.

[IMAGE OF ETL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/160BF.png)

Comment: I added an image of the ETL.  Don't have enough points to embed directly.

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question, but you can use "Delete" step to delete records from a table based on the given condition.

Comment: right, but I cant figure out how to make that condition contain the logic for "flagfield = deleted"

Comment: my mistake, I was overthinking this.  I just needed to compare the tablefield and streamfield where they are equal

Answer (score 0):

my mistake, I was overthinking this.  I just needed to compare the tablefield and streamfield where they are equal

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).